# Get URL Params from lightning to apex page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to send some url params to apex controller using lightning controller.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MartinLezer I am using a vf page in lightning so i need to pass a url params in vf page using apex controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be possible using **e.force:navigateToURL**.
Here is a method

```
copyInvestorToOtherDeal: function(component, event) {
    var dealId = component.get("{!v.recordId}");
    $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL").setParams({
        "url": "/apex/Accounts2Deal?getall=1", "deal": dealId
    }).fire();        
},
```

You can access a **deal** params in apex page.